# How to render CKeditor's rich text from a CMS into a Next.js app?

Tags: html, next.js, ckeditor, content-management-system, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I'm currently using :

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.content }}></div>
```

in order to render the rich text I get from a CKEditor input field from a Strapi CMS backend.
Is there a better way to do this that doesn't use dangerouslySetInnerHTML? I've looked into ReactMarkdown, but that seems to only work with Strapi's built-in old Markdown editor.

Answer (score 1):

Use html-react-parser library to have more control.
You will be able to change dom elements, attributes, classes,...

Answer (score 0):

In our project we are using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as well.

Comment: with dangerouslySetInnerHTML you loose the optimisation of Image tag porvided by NextJs even the Link features. that's why he does not want to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML